# 301 redirect domain/page to subdomain.domain/page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a blog on google blogger which i have recently shifted to a subdomain and taken up webhosting at godaddy.

now all my old indexed pages are giving a 404 not found error.
i want to redirect all those to subdomain.domain.com/...

all the pages were at www.indiaartndesign.com/20(something)/(something)
i want to redirect them to  inditerrain.indiaartndesign.com/20(something)/(something)

my current 301 rule is as follows but it doesnt seem to work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.indiaartndesign\.com$
RewriteRule ^2\(\.\*\)$ "http\:\/\/inditerrain\.indiaartndesign\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

You are currently escaping special characters in the first argument of your RewriteRule that actually *should* be special. You shouldn't do this. The second argument is simply a string, not a regex, so you shouldn't escape characters that are special in a regex there either, as there are no special characters in that string. You can use `$1` thru `$9` in your rewritten url to let it be replaced with the 1st thru 9th capture group in the regex of the first argument of RewriteRule. Again, more information about that is in the documentation.

You would end up with the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.indiaartndesign\.com$
RewriteRule ^(20.*)$ http://inditerrain.indiaartndesign.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: thanks a lot... works perfectly...

also is there a easier way to learn this other than reading the documentation.. like some video tutorials or something?

Comment: You can google example .htaccess files for guidance. The best way to learn regex is by trying it out. Apache uses a Perl-like regex engine, so you can use any online tool that has a preg-regex engine. I am not aware of any video tutorial, and honestly I don't think it is the best thing to teach via video.